# html form - submit search

Tags: java, html, post, submit

I have to admit, I don’t yet understand this. I am sure if I did it would be simple. I have a web template and the search is not working. Here is the code:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="search-form">
<fieldset>
<div><span>
<input type="text" value="Enter keyword here" onfocus="if(this.value=='Enter keyword here'){this.value=''}" onblur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Enter keyword here'}" />
</span><a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('search-form').submit()"><img src="images/button.gif" alt="" /></a></div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

This does not work. I have tried to insert  into the web.config file to get around the “405” error but now I get a “500” Error. This is the handlers:

```
<handlers>
        <add name="*.html Page Requests" path="*.html" verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
        <add name="*.htm Page Requests" path="*.htm" verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
</handlers>
```

Is this form code requesting java script and its not running, can someone please explain. Thanks.

Comment: Don't you need a form action to have the form submit to something? Also, why use JavaScript? Why not just a button element?

Comment: Hi Seth, I dont understand how this is working. I need to understand the process, or work flow that this code is doing. Its all built into a website template. How do I tell what java script is being called, or "POST" to? Why would I get an error "500"? Its the old skin a Cat I guess, I want to fix this problem rather than change the whole site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just follow what Seth suggested. Do not use JavaScript to submit the form. Unless you understand JavaScripts, and have a specific reason (i.e. ajax) for using JavaScript to submit form,  For example,

```
<form action="/somepath/someaction.do" method="post" id="search-form">
```

Also add an HTML button for submitting your form - see w3schools at http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi SmallWorld, is this the javaScript: document.getElementById('search-form').submit() is there a good tutorial i can have a look at anywhere that anyone can suggest? i am not the best at html or java but am fairly ok with C#. Any search scripts that anyone can suggest? Thanks for your time!

Comment: Yes, document.getElementById... is the part of JavaScript you should considering dropping. I gave you a link where you can see how simple it is to create an html form. REMEMBER: You need something on the server side to receive any data submitted through the form - if you are using asp.net then whatever code you need to write to receive submitted form data and do something with it (/somepath/some...). See the w3schools link I gave you earlier - for you to submit HTML form there is not much you need to do. If this helps, do accept the answer, otherwise it will remain an open question.

Comment: thx - I need to do more research. I still dont understand the process of transfering data. If you like the work flow of how these examples send and recieve data from the actions created in the code. action="" is where the resulting data ends up? then how is this read/recieved? The link you posted, they dont give the "form_action.asp" code. Thanks again for your time!